# Twitter background upload with API and multi form data

Tags: php, image, api, twitter

Taken from the Twitter's API section.

> **Why do my image uploads always fail?**
>   The image update methods require
>   multipart form data. They do not
>   accept a URL to an image not do they
>   accept the raw image bytes. They
>   instead require the data to be
>   delivered in the form of a file upload.

Has anyone came to a conclusion with this, or resolved this issue? I'm having various amounts of trouble trying to get it to post an image.
I've looked around and found no solutions with this.

Comment: You might need to go into more detail about how you post images and what exactly the problem is.

Comment: This is what I was previously doing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483163/updating-twitter-background-via-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exact problems are you having? From the sounds of the API, you just need to do a regular file upload to Twitter itself. The following allows you to upload a file to your server and push it to Twitter via the [API docs](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-account%C2%A0update_profile_background_image):

```
<?php
    if( $_POST ) {
        // Do anything needed for authentication
        $ch = curl_init('http://twitter.com/account/update_profile_background_image.xml');
        curl_setopt_array(array(
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('image' => '@'.$_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']),
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
        ));

        $rsp = curl_exec($ch);
        // Read the response
    }
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    File: <input type="file" name="myfile" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

More information can be found in the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) and the [cURL documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) for PHP.

Comment: How would I add this into what you wrote? $content = $to->OAuthRequest('http://twitter.com/account/update_profile_background_image.xml', array('profile_background_image_url' => $html), 'POST');

Comment: obviously the one who answered this question hasn't tested the code at all. For example, curl_setopt_array requires to be curl_setopt_array($ch, array(...  instead of curl_setopt_array(array(  . All in all the answer failed.

Comment: The code may not work as-written, but it's entirely possible it gave the original poster a clue as to the right direction.

Comment: A workable solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967831/twitter-api-updating-profile-bg-image-with-php

Comment: how do you solve this entirely in php, without the html form?